# Am I using the semicolon correctly in this example?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, semicolons

> When school is over and got nothing to do; wouldn't it be better if you could do something with your friends or family?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a comma there instead. Your sentence should also be corrected to

> When school is over and **you have** got nothing to do, wouldn't it be
>   better if you could do something with your friends or family?